# Undersampling error - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code in Matlab and I always get an error from lsim: "Τhe input signal is undersampled. Use a sampling period smaller than 0.015625."
Even though I am actually using a sampling period of 0.001. When x1 = 1.22173 the code runs fine. x1 and x2 are in radians
I am using Matlab R2016a.

```
m = 2;
L = 1;
b = 1;
g = 9.81;
x1 = 1.569051;
x2 = 0;
w = sqrt(g/(L*cos(x1)));

A = [0 1; -g*sin(x1)^2/(L*cos(x1)) -b/(m*L)];
B = [0; 2*g*sin(x1)/(L*w)];
C = [1 0; 0 1];
D = [0;0];
G = ss(A, B, C, D);

t = 0:0.001:60;
u = ones(1,length(t));
x0 = [0 ;0]; 
lsim(G,u,t,x0)
grid on;
```

Comment: Weird, matlab didn't give me an error when I ran your code. Using R2017a.

Comment: Added the matlab version I am using above. What output do you get? Is it just a straight line, or does it have oscillations?

Comment: yeah, on 2017a i get a straight line. Figured that wasn't the output you were looking for...

Comment: Not reproducible with R2016a

Comment: If you use a sampling period of 0.1 do you get the same results and no error? I have tried running the same code on two different computers but I was getting the same error. What could I be doing wrong? Did you run it from the command window or from a script?

Comment: period of 0.1 gives me an error - the same one you describe. I think it has to do with the values of A being so large when `x1 = 1.569051;`

Comment: But why when the period is smaller like the one used above, I get the error, but you don't? This is very strange.